# Create grid from 2 specific elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a grid structure using React-Grid-Layout(https://github.com/STRML/react-grid-layout).

I looked at the basic example described here:

https://github.com/STRML/react-grid-layout/blob/master/test/examples/1-basic.jsx

In this example, the layout is created using `this.props`, like this:

```
  generateLayout() {
    var p = this.props;
    return _.map(new Array(p.items), function(item, i) {
      var y = _.result(p, 'y') || Math.ceil(Math.random() * 4) + 1;
      return {x: i * 2 % 12, y: Math.floor(i / 6) * y, w: 2, h: y, i: i};
    });
  },
```

However, I don't want to display `this.props` elements in a grid. In fact, I want to place only 2 components in a grid:

```
<Comp1/>
<Comp2/>
```

How can I generate the layout for these two such that they are placed in a grid?

Answer (score 1):

React grid layout takes an object containing objects with keys - x,y,w,h.

So for 2 items in a grid with 12 columns and 12 rows you might do something like:

```
generateLayout() {
    return {{x:0,y:0,w:6,h:12},{x:6,y:0,w:6,h:12}};
}
```